# Difference in Chrome between `target="_blank"` and Right Click + `Open Link in New Tab`

Tags: html, google-chrome

Suppose I have a link to Google of the form

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

There are a couple different ways to open this link in a new tab:

1. Left click on the link
2. Right click on the link and select `Open Link in New Tab`

I've noticed on an app I work on that there is different behavior between #1 and #2. For example, when I console out `window.opener` for #1 I get an object like

[image: window.opener left clicking on a link with target="_blank"]

wheres #2 gives me `undefined`.

What are the differences between these two ways to open the link? I can't find any information about how a browser (in my case, Chrome), might handle these cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, two different behaviors were happening in those two cases in an application I was working on. I had to search everywhere to see why, only to find your question that helped me identify the problem.

in case #1, of course when you left click the link, the user is giving the developer the choice of whither to open in a new tab. whereas in case #2, the user is making the choice instead.

case #1 is like doing `window.open(URL, '_blank');`
case #2 is like opening a new tab and manually typing the URL;

the only thing I found is that when you open the URL with target blank (case #1), that new tab or window will link to the parent (opener) by `window.opener` until you close that window, the opener will be back to `null`

as far as behavior, the source code of the new URL may include logic on window.opener you may need to search if this was the case. I don't see why the browser would treat them differently, it has to be from the source code.